# Angular 4: http client module get request. API Key placement

Tags: angular, get, httpclient

When making an api call using HttpClientModule in ionic/angular4, where do I put the api key? The site I'm calling says to use curl this curl command:

```
curl -X GET https://jsonodds.com/api/odds -H "JsonOdds-API-Key: 
yourapikey"
```

How should I change this code to include the api key?:

```
 apiUrl = "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl"

 getNFL() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     this.http.get(this.apiUrl).subscribe(data => {
     resolve(data);
   },   err => {
  console.log(err);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following code:

```
apiUrl = "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl"

 getNFL() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     this.http.get(this.apiUrl, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set("JsonOdds-API-Key", "your-api-key")).subscribe(data => {
     resolve(data);
   },   err => {
  console.log(err);
   });
 });
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting this error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.subscribe is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

With an custom interceptor the api key can be added automatically to every http call. If you want know more about interceptors [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses) is a start to read.

apikey.interceptor.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // add the header to the cloned request
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('JsonOdds-API-Key', 'yourapikey')});

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Do not forget to register your interceptor in the `AppModule`.

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

import {ApiKeyInterceptor} from 'apikey.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ApiKeyInterceptor,
    multi: true,
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'JsonOdds-API-Key', 'yourapikey'
  })
};

 apiUrl = "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds/nfl"

 getNFL() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     this.http.get(this.apiUrl,httpOptions ).subscribe(data => {
     resolve(data);
   },   err => {
  console.log(err);
   });
 });

//new HttpHeaders().set method is used to return a clone of the current instance with the new changes applied.
```